# Cannot decode base64 string from jquery ajax header in C# web api basic authentication filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a jquery ajax call that needs to pass an auth header. I've tried several different approaches. But my ajax call currently looks like this...

```
        $.ajax({
        headers: {"Authorization": "Basic YgBhAHMAaQBjACAAbAAxAHQAdABsADMAcAAxAGcAbAAxAHQAdABsADMAcAAxAGcAOgBsADMAKwBtADMAMQBuAA=="},
        url: fetchurl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                $('<option/>').attr('value', val.ProductCd)
                    .html(val.ProductCd + " - " + val.Description)
                    .appendTo(productselect);
            });
            $.unblockUI();
        },
        error: function (error, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

I thought my decoding problems might have to do with who was doing the encoding, so I generated that token via the C# class and pasted it into my script code.

I've also tried using plugins for encoding in jquery and using the beforesend callback to set the header.

Here I try to decode:

```
          string authToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
          string decodedToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authToken));



          string username = decodedToken.Substring(0, decodedToken.IndexOf(":"));
          string password = decodedToken.Substring(decodedToken.IndexOf(":") + 1);
```

My result is pretty much always the same.

After decoding the auth header I get garbage: 
"�w0u�\n�ZXNTLMSSP\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X\0\0\0��\0\0\0I���ۛ��l�Y��#��\0\0\0��P-\"��\0\0\0\0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. It took some hacking but I finally figured out that while I was sending a basic auth from my ajax call, the web api layer was receiving a negotiate auth. So I went into IIS disabled all auth on the web service save for anonymous. And then voila.